# Is there a way to mask Gitlab environment variables outside of the UI

Tags: security, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to mask dynamically retrieved and set tokens during Gitlab CI pipelines, however, the only way I can see masking being set is predefined pipeline variables.

Is there a way to flag a variable during the pipeline as masked? I SWEAR I had seen something like this in the past, but for the life of me I cannot find it.

```
export SECRET=$(get secret somehow)
echo $SECRET #secrettext
```

Is there a way to mask this on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GitLab CI doesn't offer this feature. You cannot dynamically register additional values for masking in the job log. GitLab will only mask CICD variables [marked for masking](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#mask-a-cicd-variable) in the project settings or values defined and retrieved through the [secrets keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#secrets) (e.g., Vault secrets).

> I SWEAR I had seen something like this in the past

You may be thinking of the [add-mask feature](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-a-log) in *GitHub Actions*.